# Clang 10 link error with boost-thread on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, linux, boost, clang, lld

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 with clang/lld 7 and boost 1.65 to 20.04 with clang/lld 10 and boost 1.71, I have encountered a linker errors that I don't know how to address. Is clang & boost on Ubuntu 20.04 known to be an incompatible pair? What are my options to get things compiling on Ubuntu 20.04 using clang?

The minimal example of the error is

```
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>
int main() {
  boost::shared_mutex sm;
}
```

Notes:

- It works just fine with GCC 9 and gold linker.
- The clang + gold linker combo fails with very much the same error message and bfd linker fails with a very short one which I'll show the output for below as well.
- The same errors occur with clang/lld 9 instead of 10.

I have created a minimal example that can easily be reproduced in a ubuntu 20.04 system or container, for my reproduction I used the plain `ubuntu:focal` container from dockerhub.

1. Install clang/lld 10 and boost 1.71

```
apt update && apt install clang lld libboost-thread-dev
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/ld" "ld" "/usr/bin/ld.lld-10" 30
```

Now all requirements are installed and LLD is the default linker.

2. create minimal example and compile/link it

```
root@d66452260792:/# cat x.cpp 
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>
int main() {
  boost::shared_mutex sm;
}

root@d66452260792:/# clang -lboost_thread x.cpp
```

3. Expected result:

```
successful compilation
```

4. Actual result

- with BFD linker (GNU ld 2.34):

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/x-a145e4.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE@@CXXABI_1.3'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

- with LLD 10 as linker (but gold linker errors looks very similar):

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: std::allocator<char>::allocator()
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::generic_error_category_message[abi:cxx11](int))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::generic_error_category_message[abi:cxx11](int))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::allocator<char>::~allocator()
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::generic_error_category_message[abi:cxx11](int))
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::generic_error_category_message[abi:cxx11](int))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::_V2::generic_category()
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::std_category::equivalent(int, std::error_condition const&) const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::std_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::std_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const)

ld: error: undefined symbol: typeinfo for std::_V2::error_category
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::std_category::equivalent(int, std::error_condition const&) const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::std_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(typeinfo for boost::system::detail::std_category)

ld: error: undefined symbol: __dynamic_cast
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::std_category::equivalent(int, std::error_condition const&) const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::std_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const)

ld: error: undefined symbol: __cxa_begin_catch
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(__clang_call_terminate)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::error_category::message(int, char*, unsigned long) const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(void std::_Rb_tree<boost::system::error_category const*, std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > >, boost::system::detail::cat_ptr_less, std::allocator<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > > >::_M_construct_node<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > >(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > >*, std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > >&&))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::terminate()
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(__clang_call_terminate)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::empty() const
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::runtime_error::what() const
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(char const*)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::error_category::message(int, char*, unsigned long) const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::~system_error())

ld: error: undefined symbol: __cxa_end_catch
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::error_category::message(int, char*, unsigned long) const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(void std::_Rb_tree<boost::system::error_category const*, std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > >, boost::system::detail::cat_ptr_less, std::allocator<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > > >::_M_construct_node<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > >(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > >*, std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > >&&))

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::what() const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::error_category::message(int, char*, unsigned long) const)

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::_V2::error_category::~error_category()
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::std_category::~std_category())

ld: error: undefined symbol: operator delete(void*)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::std_category::~std_category())
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::~system_error())
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::to_std_category(boost::system::error_category const&))
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > >*, unsigned long))
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error>::~error_info_injector())
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::thread_resource_error::~thread_resource_error())
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::thread_exception::~thread_exception())
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> >::~clone_impl())
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> >::clone() const)
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::wrapexcept<boost::thread_resource_error>::~wrapexcept())

ld: error: undefined symbol: std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::~system_error())
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::system_error::system_error(boost::system::system_error const&))

ld: error: undefined symbol: __cxa_guard_acquire
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::to_std_category(boost::system::error_category const&))
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::to_std_category(boost::system::error_category const&))
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-dd4c59.o:(boost::system::detail::to_std_category(boost::system::error_category const&))

ld: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use -error-limit=0 to see all errors)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: A general tip: Never work on your system as `root`. Always work as an ordinary user. Working as `root` is an enormous security risk.

Comment: This is in a minimal container created only for the minimal example. I don't normally work as root.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, order matters when linking with libraries. Always put libraries *last* on the command line.

Secondly, `boost_thread` depends on the `boost_system` library (which should be listed *before* `boost_thread`).

Thirdly, the `clang` front-end program is for linking C programs, not C++. For C++ use `clang++`.

To use POSIX thread functionality on supported systems, one also needs to use the `-pthread` flag when building.

So to put it all together:

```
$ clang++ -pthread x.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

Comment: This does indeed change things, but it doesn't solve everything. I still get this: ```root@b3afdc7eb046:/# clang++ x.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread
ld: error: undefined symbol: pthread_condattr_setclock
>>> referenced by x.cpp
>>>               /tmp/x-9b1f30.o:(boost::condition_variable::condition_variable())
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```

Comment: @SeverinFichtl Updated, another flag needed when building